# Typescript Compilation Issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, mean-stack, visual-studio-code

Typescript current version is 1.6.2, but when I am installing typescript and checking the version through "tsc -v" it gives me typescript version 1.0.3.0, due to which I am not being able to compile typescript.
Kindly tell me what should I do now. Need some serious help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

This installs the latest typescript globally:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Comment: I have installed typescript using this but unfortunately the version I am getting is 1.0.3.0.

Comment: checkout where npm installed typescript and where tsc gets called from via which tsc.

Comment: Typescript is installed in C:\Users\Waleed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript
And I am writing tsc in cmd like this
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tsc -v

Comment: Run `where tsc`. You probably have it installed with Visual studio and need to uninstall it from control panel (or edit your `PATH` to remove that version)

Comment: may be a dumb suggestion. did you close and reopen cmd prompt? i have same issue and once restarted, version shows correct.